# First Flutter gradle build failed (what went wrong:- java/lang/Throwable$WrappedPrintWriter)

Tags: flutter, gradle, flutter-build

I am trying to build first flutter project only and it shows gradle build failed, I don't understand why is this happening I searched a lot and no solution worked for me. I am started working on flutter again after some time.

In flutter doctor everything shows fine, pug get is working.
I did flutter upgrade and then run and still it is not working.

Can somebody help?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java/lang/Throwable$WrappedPrintWriter

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1198], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.4 at D:\flutter
    • Framework revision 1aafb3a8b9 (3 weeks ago), 2020-11-13 09:59:28 -0800
    • Engine revision 2c956a31c0
    • Dart version 2.10.4
    • Pub download mirror https://pub.dev

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at D:\Android\SDK
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = D:\Android\SDK
    • Java binary at: D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 48.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.8052
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[√] VS Code (version 1.51.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\vishnu Agarwal\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.16.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM G770F (mobile) • RF8N217YVLX • android-arm64 • Android 10 (API 29)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: use `flutter doctor` on terminal  and add the output to the question please

Comment: @AkshitOstwal I have added output of flutter doctor

Comment: have you cloned the project from somewhere??

Comment: @AkshitOstwal No I just tried to run default flutter project, after creating new flutter project.

Comment: check the last comment on this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63107 and see if the issue resolves

Comment: also meanwhile try `flutter clean`  and build

Comment: @AkshitOstwal sorry both of them didn't worked for me

Comment: than I think raising an issue on flutter's GitHub  repo would be right choice for now

Comment: also don't forget to add these outputs as well as `flutter doctor -v`, your `flutter run --verbose` and your `pubspec.yaml` too